# How to publish ansible-galaxy role in my organization name?

Tags: ansible, ansible-galaxy

I am connected to Ansible Galaxy and my company Organization allows ansible-galaxy to index its GitHub repositories and is correctly listed as a "namespace" provider.

However, when I try to add a new role with "add content", it is added as a content for my username and not of my organization name.

How can I tell ansible-galaxy to register the role under my company name?

Comment: Yeah, same issue. My login is one thing, but my ansible roles are published under a company organization.

Comment: Have you linked your personal account and relevant organisations, as seen in https://galaxy.ansible.com/docs/_images/login-04.png ?

Comment: Yes I did sir, still no success

Answer (score 0):

Your specifc problem (adding an organization name) seems to be a [current issue on galaxy](https://github.com/ansible/galaxy/issues/1575).

For others looking for a similar issue when trying to add a namespace to an *existing* organization in Galaxy and this not appearing: in GitHub, on organization settings, under third-party access, I found necessary to disable the restrictions on third-party access policy.